# How to compile init.cpp in roscpp package?

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use sudo to edit init.cpp.

But whenever I add wrong syntax on that src, I can rosmake successfully on roscpp package and roscomm package.

Why roscpp & roscomm can't detect some sources are changed?

How can I compile /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/src/libros/init.cpp ?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12357/how-to-compile-init.cpp-in-roscpp-package?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-12-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-12-15**:
Why are you editing init.cpp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first reason would be that there probably is a ROS_NOBUILD file, so the package will not be built.

If it were not there you would probably get permission denied problems.

You should never edit any code that is installed in /opt.
If you need to edit init.cpp, checkout the source code locally and overlay the path in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, i.e. [Install ROS from source](http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu/Source).

Other than that, I would second Mac's question: Why are you editing init.cpp?

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-12-18**:
You just put it in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH in front of the original ROS stacks.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-12-17**:
I found that makefile doesn't support 'install' command. If I checkout roscpp and rosmake it, how to install it? Or just rosmake? Does it will conflict   with the original roscpp package in /opt/...?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-12-17**:
Yes, definitely. Just install roscpp from sources.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-12-16**:
What I mean is 'Can I change roscpp sources & compile & install it in order to write new ros c++ node with my roscpp packages?'.  If I can do that, I just have powerful tool to trace the procedure of roscpp, so that I can write C# client libraries in the future.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-12-16**:
Well, for playing around with roscpp/init.cpp follow the source checkout method, i.e. build ROS basic functionality locally. I don't understand what you mean with the second comment.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-12-16**:
By the way, is there any existing method to change source and rosmake to make some effect?

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-12-16**:
Because I want to trace how roscpp implement by using change sources to figure out the whole procedure in order to implement C# client libraries. I found just by reading docs is not enough.